# What would Superman see if he was exposed to Scarecrow's 'fear toxin'?

Tags: dc, superman

We are familiar with Johnathan Crane a.k.a The Scarecrow's fear toxin. It induces in the victim hallucinations and according to [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Scarecrow%27s_Fear_Toxin),

> *When inhaled, the victim hallucinates their own worst fears becoming a reality.*

**So, what would the Man of Steel experience/see when he is under the influence of the fear toxin? In other words, what is his greatest fear?**

Comment: This is probably a bit subjective unless there's a source that directly quotes this. However, there are some Superman storylines that involve Superman being used either against his will or in a deceptive manner that results in him causing some great calamity on Earth and he seems to go to some lengths to ensure this doesn't happen. Also: probably anything that negatively impacts Lois Lane.

Comment: Quora [What is Superman's greatest fear?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Supermans-greatest-fear)

Comment: I suggest Doomsday.

Comment: Well, this one goes back a ways and addresses only his most feared foe, not his greatest fear, per se.  In World's Finest 173, Supes revealed that his most feared foe was a guy named Kralik.  http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_173

Comment: I would imagine superman would be immune to the fear toxin unless Crane reformulated it to include some powdered green rocks

Comment: @Revenant - He did (or rather the Joker did it).

Comment: A monster made of Kryptonite..

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt It looks like World's Finest 173 was released in 1968. Kralik is described as "almost as powerful as Superman" (but absolutely ruthless). This doesn't seem to compare to Doomsday.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Superman has been sprayed with the Scarecrow's "fear toxin" on at least one occasion, in [Injustice: Gods Amongst Us Vol. 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injustice:_Gods_Among_Us_(comic_book)).

**When that happened he saw Doomsday.**

[image]

In [Batman/Superman #37 (Torment)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman/Batman_Vol_1_37) he was zapped with a ray that caused him to see his

> "primal fears"

In that instance he saw generic monsters, Lois pinned under a fallen spar and the world turned to Kryptonite.

[image]